# Get real time data to django models from a external webpage

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-models, beautifulsoup

I have a Django app and some of the models I want to get data in real-time from external sources.

```
class Register(models.Model):
   student_id=models.IntegerField() 
   temperature=models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

The data I want this model to hold can only be accessed from another website. I have tried to create a web scrapy to get real-time data but it is not efficient. If there is an efficient way to handle this let me.

Comment: Could you share what data you are trying to fetch from and how often ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a background task that requires some more infrastructure than a basic web server. I would recommend using docker-compose to set up:

1. task-scheduler - I recommend [celery-beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)
2. messaging-queue - I recommend [redis](https://redis.io/) or [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
3. celery-worker - This is a [Django-Package](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) that allows background tasks to be triggered and handled based on code inside Django
4. flower - This is a [queue-managing tool](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with a nice UI to see what is going on inside of the celery-worker and messaging-queue

This will allow you to spawn a task based on a cron-schedule that can interact with your Django app and pull the actual data you need. You will need to set up your own Docker for the celery-worker & the django web-server but flower, rabbitmq/redis, and celery-beat all have public images you can reference directly in docker-compose. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking, the optimal way is not to fetch data all the time, but to act only when data is changed. So, if you are in control of this external website, I would suggest for you to trigger an event (send a request) to a webhook configured in Django. If you have too many requests a queue service is a good option to handle this.

If you don't control the data source, then I guess you have to schedule a task to constantly fetch data, but I would suggest you set up an external service (or container) to do this, for you not to create overhead on Django